# MySQL order is returning in (unwanted) random order

Tags: mysql

In my database I have some records where I am sorting by what happens to be a NULL value:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| row1 | NULL |
| row2 | NULL |

SELECT ... ORDER BY col2
```

Even though all the values are the same (NULL), I would expect MySQL to return the results in a consistent order, but they are apparently random. I run the query a hundred times and every so often the results are returned in a different order. I can't find any MySQL documentation on this. Is there a bug? Or is this a documented "feature"?

Comment: Where/what is the "limit" specification, if any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.  The database engine is free to return the rows in any order as long as the "Order By" is honoured.  If you want consistency then try:

```
select ... order by col2, some-unique-id
```

Where some-unique-id is a column in the table that is unique.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. I can easily add a second order by clause, but I just wanted to know if the results of using one order by clause was going to be consistent or random.

Answer (score 0):

change your query to

> select .... order by col2, col1

or any other column you need